# src attribute ignores the embeded link if it remains the same

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I am loading images via Controller action like bellow:

```
  <img src="@Url.Action("EditImage", "Image", new {id = Model.ShopId, isView = true})" alt="@Model.ImageName"/>
```

In chrome this action will get called only once and then if i don't reload the page the browser is assuming that link remained the same and it doesn't call it again.

My problem is the link will always remain unchanged, because it's passing the shopId parameter to the function and since shop has got a single image when i change it, I'd still call the same link to get the new image.

Comment: Please be more specific, is not clear what is your problem. You generate a link, and obviously it will not change if you do not reload the page, this is how browsers work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending a query string to the `src` attribute with a date-time value will effectively prevent the browser from cacheing the image.

Would be interested to see the model to and/or controller to see if that `src` calculation could be cleaner, would be more efficient to calculate the image path server side than being interpreted on the fly.

Comment: I figured that myself as well, what i am seeking for is maybe some more elegant solution of possible.

Comment: You are fighting the desirable caching of the browser. Your choices are either to vary the URL or sending a no-cache directive on the image. I would recommend against the latter so that the end-users dont have to load images every time

Comment: I get that, what would be the reason for image actions not being displayed in network traffic section at least labelled as cached?

Comment: Could be related to how Chrome events fire concerning the image still being in the web-cache or if it is in the disc-cache, the latter of which would redo the request and 304

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate your action method or controller with

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```